# Works for Short Input, Fails for Long Input. How to Solve?

Tags: c, string, search, cstring, runtime-error

I've this program which finds substring in a string. It works for small inputs. But fails for long inputs. Here's the program:

```
//Find Substring in given String
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
  //Variable Initialization
  int i=0,j=0,k=0;
  char sentence[50],temp[50],search[50];

  //Gets Strings
  printf("Enter Sentence: ");
  fgets(sentence,50,stdin);
  printf("Enter Search: ");
  fgets(search,50,stdin);

  //Actual Work Loop
  while(sentence[i]!='\0')
  {
    k=i;j=0;
    while(sentence[k]==search[j])
    {
      temp[j]=sentence[k];
      j++;
      k++;
    }
    if(strcmp(temp,search)==0)
      break;
   i++;
  }

  //Output Printing
  printf("Found string at: %d \n",k-strlen(search));
}
```

Works for:

```
Enter Sentence: good evening
Enter Search: evening
Found string at 6
```

Fails for:

```
Enter Sentence: dear god please make this work
Enter Search: make
Found string at 25
```

Which is totally wrong. Can any expert find me a solution?

**P.S:** This is kinda like reinventing the wheel since strstr() has this functionality. But I'm trying for a non-library way of doing it.

Comment: Ugh. Fortran77 is dead. Can you please use better variable names. You make my head hurt :)

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: I admit to having programmed in FORTRAN 77 professionally as recently as last year. However, I think i, j, k are perfectly legitimate loop control variables. Short scopes of visibility justify short variable names, IMO.

Comment: I have no problem with i. I won't bat an eyelash at j. i,jk, is pushing it - especially outside of for loop context where things start getting muddled.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `strncmp` rather than `strcmp` and set the comparison length equal to `strlen(search)`. Either that or you could just terminate temp with a `'\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to start with, "temp" won't be null terminated in the second case.  That's why your first case works; it wouldn't work if you'd searched for "good."

Comment: Good catch! That may have nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to avoid the strcmp completely, you are already doing 99% of its work.  Just check j against your token/search string length upon exit of your compare loop and you'll know if you have a match.